# No headphone sound on a 2011 iMac

Tags: sound, 12.04, headphones

Sound works fine from the internal speakers from my iMac 2011, but the headphone and microphone jack seem to have no output/input. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Open up a terminal and enter ***alsamixer***. Navigate with the left and right arrows, unmute by pressing m and change the volume by using up or down.

Out of all of the solutions I have tried this is the only one that worked on my Intel® Core™2 CPU T7600 @ 2.33GHz × 2 Macbook Pro.  And it is so easy to do!

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to get my headphone jack to work on my iMac.  Nothing worked except upgrade the kernel to the `3.7.2` version.

As soon as I did that, all sound issues went away.

Update:
My apologies as I'm new to posting anything here.  I followed the instructions on upubuntu:
http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/01/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-372-in.html

Then, I recently upgraded to 3.7.3 and all sound works just fine:
http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/01/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-373-in.html

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: It would be nice if you edit your answer and upload information about *How did you upgrade the kernel*.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in more than one place. When tempted to do so, this usually means that either: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, or (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question. (You can flag posts once you gain [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts) on the site.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the mixer settings after you connect the earphones? Mine (although I'm still on 11.10), whenever I plugged in the earphones, the volume gets muted automatically.

If the mixer settings are fine in your gui, open up a terminal and check `alsamixer`. Navigate with the left and right arrows, unmute by pressing `m` and change the volume by using up or down. `esc` will exit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the alsamixer option only works until you unplug the headphones. then it goes back to muted. The 3.7.3 kernal resolved the issue for me. Thanks for the tip!!!

http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/01/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-373-in.html