# Lost Sound To Headphone Jack After Recent Update (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, sound

After a recent update, I lost all sound to my headphone jacks on an HP Pavilion dv6. Not sure where to begin. Does anyone have any ideas? The external speakers on my laptop work fine.

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue using the information here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121721/no-headphone-sound-on-a-2011-imac?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Add the `alsa-daily` PPA by running by the command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
```

Update your packages list with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the `alsa-hda-dkms` package:

sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms

Reboot, and see the result! (This worked for me.)

***Source:* [Sound from both headphones and speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/answer/submit)**